# Is there a way to pass an instance of a Selenium Webdriver profile into several functions with Python

Tags: python, function, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a script that will be able to handle several possibilities based on the input csv file. It will determine which webpages to visit, and what content to create/upload. I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python.

I would like to have it set up so that each function is in a separate file called by the parent file.

Is there a way to create a firefox profile, then pass that profile into a function to log in. Then pass that same profile into a different function to upload specific content. I would like it to be able to pass the profile to however many functions are needed without needing to create a new profile for each uploading instance?

Right now I have it set up as a single function that just has all possibilities written in it. I would much prefer to simplify it into separate functions that are only called as needed.

Is this possible? and if so how?

I am using Python 2.7

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could simply create the profile, then use it as an argument in the different functions as you call them. For instance, suppose you have the Firefox profile below:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_folder)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/plain")
```

Then you use that Firefox profile as an argument of other functions:

```
def your_function1(fp):
    # a bunch of code
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)

def your_function2(fp):
    # a bunch of code
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = fp)

# etc
```

And then you just call these functions as needed.

Comment: wow, thanks. For some reason, I thought I'd have to pass in all the arguments about its preferences. That works. Thank you.